# Ubuntu arm precise and hydro?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki page

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM

says "Due to limited resources, there are only active builds for Raring armhf, since this appear to be the most popular Ubuntu distribution in use on ARM."

What is that claim based on? The groovy page said that it was Precise that was the most popular. And checking for example the Linaro page for gumstix:

http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=Installing_Linaro_Image

it seems to still be based on Precise.

So is it possible to get a hydro Precise build for armhf also?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77576/ubuntu-arm-precise-and-hydro?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do these builds on my personal desktop, and it usually takes about a week to produce a mostly-complete build.

When I wrote the Groovy documentation 6-8 months ago, Precise appeared to be the most popular Ubuntu distribution for ARM boards such as the beaglebone and Pandaboard.

When doing the latest builds for Hydro about a month ago, and taking to people who were looking for more recent builds of ROS, I chose Ubuntu Raring because it has much better support for recent boards such as the BeagleBone Black.

I have no intention of removing the old Groovy builds for Precise. They may not get updated very frequently, but I have no plans to remove them either.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-11**:
Btw, thanks for the effort of setting this ARM build farm up and keeping it running!

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-09-11**:
Are you cross compiling of what are you using to build the arm packages? Do you have any written instructions about how to set up a build for armhf? If I get some time over I might want to experiment a bit with this...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-09-12**:
I'm running a clone of the main ROS build farm. The setup instructions are loosely documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is based on feedback from various forums which Austin has been communicating.  As mentioned the limitation for building on ARM is mostly resources.  It is possible, but the resources are not available at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-09-10**:
I hope you will not remove the groovy Precise arm build since I will stay with this since I cannot find any good support for Gumstix Overo and Raring. And for me the build is more important for these kind of embedded computers were you do not want to build natively.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-09-10**:
Also both comments about popularity cannot be true at the same time so the formulation ought to be changed on one page...

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-09-11**:
Wouldn't it make sense to maintain builds for the Ubuntu LTS version as a priority? Not everyone would be eager to continually upgrade their Operating System everytime a new version of ROS comes out just to use the pre-built packages.